# Is there a Way to Switch Stores when clicking on categoires?

Tags: magento2

I am building a website that will have multiple stores. From the main websites i want the categories to be the place to switch websites. Is there anyway i can switch to another website when a button is clicked? I've Tried URL Rewrites but since the URL has the store code it dosent direct to the other website. I've Provided an example image of what i want the categories to be like.[image: Example]

Comment: Please check the below answer and update me.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/367928/82670

Answer (score 0):

create a new custom module.

create a controller,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $storeCode = 'your_store_code'; // Replace with the desired store code
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getIdByCode($storeCode);
        $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->setCurrentStore($storeCode);
        $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()); // Redirect to the previous page
    }
}
```

create route configuration.

Create a layout file at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/switch_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.view.form">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="switch_website_button" after="-" template="Vendor_Module::switch_website_button.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create a template file at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/switch_website_button.phtml**

```
    <div>
    <button class="action switch-website-button" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('switch/index/index')) ?>';">
        Switch to Another Website
    </button>
</div>
```

I hope it is of assistance to you.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/Msquare/StoreWebsiteRedirect**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category Msquare
 * @package Msquare_StoreWebsiteRedirect
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Msquare_StoreWebsiteRedirect',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Msquare/StoreWebsiteRedirect/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * @category Msquare
 * @package Msquare_StoreWebsiteRedirect
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Msquare_StoreWebsiteRedirect" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Msquare/StoreWebsiteRedirect/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category Msquare
 * @package Msquare_StoreWebsiteRedirect
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="add_website_store_to_nav" type="Msquare\StoreWebsiteRedirect\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Msquare/StoreWebsiteRedirect/Plugin/Block**

**Topmenu.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category Msquare
 * @package Msquare_StoreWebsiteRedirect
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace Msquare\StoreWebsiteRedirect\Plugin\Block;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

class Topmenu
{
   /**
    * @var UrlInterface
    */
    protected $urlBuilder;

   /**
    * @var StoreManagerInterface
    */
    protected $storeManager;

   /**
    * @var EncoderInterface
    */
   private $encoder;


    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        EncoderInterface $encoder
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }


    public function afterGetHtml(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topmenu, $html)
    {
        foreach ($this->getWebsites() as $websiteKey => $websiteVal) {
            $websiteUrl = $this->getStoreRedirectUrl($websiteVal->getDefaultStore());
            $html .= "<li class='level0 nav-".$websiteVal->getId()." category-item level-top parent ui-menu-item'>";
            $html .= "<a href='".$websiteUrl."' class='level-top ui-menu-item-wrapper' aria-haspopup='true' tabindex='-1' role='menuitem'>";
            $html .= "<span class='ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-caret-1-e'></span>";
            $html .= "<span>".$websiteVal->getName()."</span>";
            $html .= "</a>";
            $html .= "<ul class='level0 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front' role='menu' aria-expanded='false' style='display: none; top: 47.0138px; left: 0px;' aria-hidden='true'>";
            foreach ($websiteVal->getStores() as $storeKey => $storeVal) {
                $storeUrl = $this->getStoreRedirectUrl($storeVal);
                $html .= "<li class='level1 nav-".$websiteVal->getId()."-".$storeVal->getId()." category-item first last ui-menu-item'>";
                $html .= "<a href='".$storeUrl."'  tabindex='-1' role='menuitem' class='ui-menu-item-wrapper'>";
                $html .= "<span>".$storeVal->getName()."</span>";
                $html .= "</a>";
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
            $html .= "</ul>";
            $html .= "</li>";
        }
        return $html;
    }

    public function getWebsites()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getWebsites();
    }

    public function getStoreRedirectUrl(Store $store): string
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
            'stores/store/redirect',
            [
                '___store' => $store->getCode(),
                '___from_store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode(),
                ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->encoder->encode(
                    $store->getCurrentUrl(false)
                ),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**OutPut:**

[image]